# Gitlab CI. Error response from daemon: No such image

Tags: docker, gitlab

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:stable
...
...

heroku_publishing:
    stage: publish_image
    services:
        - docker:dind
    script:
        - docker login --username=_ --password=$HEROKU_AUTH_KEY registry.heroku.com
        - docker login --username=$DOCKER_LOGIN --password=$DOCKER_PASSWORD
        - docker tag fagam32/study_project_backend:latest registry.heroku.com/study-project-backend/release
        - docker push registry.heroku.com/study-project-backend/release
#    needs:
#        - build
    allow_failure: false
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    image: buddy/heroku-cli:latest
    script:
        - heroku container:release release
    needs:
        - heroku_publishing
    when: manual
```

I'm trying to tag image to push it to heroku image registry. Locally it works fine, but job fails with such message:

```
$ docker tag fagam32/study_project_backend:latest registry.heroku.com/study-project-backend/release
Error response from daemon: No such image: fagam32/study_project_backend:latest
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `tag` only works on local images, so you'd have to `docker pull` the source image first, then tag it, then push it to Heroku's Registry

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thank you)

Answer (score 4):

Just do `docker pull` before tagging and everything works fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: docker pull and ? (command not work)